# How to get all included projects?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project setup (no subprojects).

In my `settings.gradle` I have something like:

```
include 'proj-a', 'lib-b'
project( ':proj-a' ).projectDir = file( '../proj-a' )
project( ':lib-b' ).projectDir = file( '../lib-b' )
```

How can I get a list of all included projects in my `build.gradle`?

I tried `allprojects`, `subprojects`, `gradle.includedBuilds` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the projects included using `include` will be subprojects to an implicit root project in the same directory as the `settings.gradle` file. Of course, you may ignore this project, as it does not even need a `build.gradle` file.

To access all the projects use `rootProject.subprojects`, because `rootProject.allprojects` would include the implicit root project.

As an additional hint, you may use `includeFlat` instead of setting the project directories manually:

```
includeFlat 'proj-a', 'lib-b'
```

Comment: `println subprojects` gives `[]`

Comment: As I explained to you in my answer, you need to use `println rootProject.subprojects`.